# How can I update data from an external process?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vue 2 component.  It has a data attribute which I need to update based on an external event happening.  I can't work out how to get this to happen.  I'm happy to consider events or direct binding, watchers, anything, I just am completely baffled by the various examples on the internet that make this seem easy, but none of them work :(

I can't pass a prop down through from the top level Vue instance, because I'm using a library which supplies its own components and they are between my top level and my own components...

I'm using Vue 2.5 and my component is registered using `Vue.component()`...

Main HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <f7-app :params="f7params">
        <f7-view id="main-view" main>
            <f7-page>
                <f7-navbar>
                    <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                        <div class="header-logo-container"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></div>
                        <div class="left back-btn"><a href="#" class="link icon-only invisible"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></div>
                        <div class="right settings-btn"><a href="#" class="link icon-only"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a></div>
                    </div>
                </f7-navbar>
                <f7-toolbar>
                    <ym-toolbar></ym-toolbar>
                </f7-toolbar>
                <ym-rootmaps></ym-rootmaps>
            </f7-page>
        </f7-view>
    </f7-app>
</div>
```

Vue Component registration

```
var rootMapsComponent = Vue.component('ym-rootmaps', {
    template: '#rootmaps',
    props: ['menuitem'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            customMenu: window.customMenuJSON,
            rootMaps: window.rootMaps,
            rootAreaImageLocation: rootAreaImageLocation
        };
    },
    created: function () {
        // `this` points to the vm instance
        console.log('Created Root Maps Component');
    }
}); 

// Init App
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function () {
    return {
    // Framework7 parameters here
    f7params: {
        root: '#app', // App root element
        id: 'io.framework7.testapp', // App bundle ID
        name: 'Framework7', // App name
        theme: 'md', // Automatic theme detection
        // App routes
        routes: [],
    },
    rootMaps: {},
    }
},
created: function () {
    // `this` points to the vm instance
    console.log('Created Main App');
    documentReady();
    this.$on('rootmapsUpdated', function(arg) {
        console.log('rootmapsUpdated');
        console.log(this);
        this.rootMaps = window.rootAreas;
    });
}
});
```

I'd like to be able to update `rootMaps` on demand from an external call to this page.  I'm happy to fire an event using `vm.$emit` but don't know how to get the component to listen for it (I managed to get the top level app instance to listen for the event, but nothing further down than that)

Any thoughts, hints, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on using `emit` in vuejs

in your app.js add `Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();`

**component 1**

trigger event by using:

```
methods:{
    trigger() {
        this.$bus.$emit('throw-event', sample_data)
    }
}
```

**component 2**

then this is how you listen:

```
mounted () {
    this.$bus.$on('throw-event', ($data) => {
       console.log($data) // this will throw the `sample_data` in your emit
    })
}
```